# Is there any way to get the optimization time in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I'd like to see how long it takes to optimize a query. Does PostgreSQL support this feature?

Comment: I don't think so. There's no way to get the inside work of the optimizer - which is the answer of that question - but what I'm asking here is outside of the optimizer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, starting with Postgres 9.4 this information is included in the execution plan when using the `analyze` option:

```
psql (9.4.1)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=> explain (analyze,verbose)
postgres-> select count(*)
postgres-> from product;
                                                                             QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=8431.92..8431.92 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=132.491..132.491 rows=1 loops=1)
   Output: count(*)
   ->  Index Only Scan using product_pkey on public.product  (cost=0.42..7181.92 rows=500000 width=0) (actual time=0.622..91.129 rows=500000 loops=1)
         Output: product_id
         Heap Fetches: 8
 Planning time: 2.756 ms
 Execution time: 132.614 ms
(7 rows)
```

Comment: Good to know! I've been using 9.3 so I didn't know that. Thanks!